# A subclass of metacyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

A group $G$ is **metacyclic** if it contains a cyclic normal subgroup $N$, such that $G/N$ is also cyclic. $N$ is called the **kernel**, and the order of $G/N$ is the **index** of the metacyclic group. There is an alternative definition (see Hempel, Comm. Algebra 28(8), 2000):

A group $G$ is metacyclic with a kernel of order $m$ and index $n$ if, and only if, it has a presentation of the form 
$$\langle a, b: a^n = b^l, b^m = 1, a^{-1}ba = b^r \rangle$$
where $n, l, m, r$ are positive integers, such that $r^n \equiv 1 (m)$ and $m|l(r-1)$. Now, replacing $b$ by a suitable power of itself, we may assume that $l|m$. In particular, I have been working with $l=m$. My question is:

What implies this restriction $l=m$? I.e. what subclass of metacyclic groups would that be?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your group has order $m\cdot n$, as $\langle b\rangle$ has order $m$ and index $n$. You also have that $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=1$, so your group is the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_n\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_m$, where the action is dependent on the $r$ and the $n$ (the other two bits of the semidirect product criteria are immediate).

Comment: These are called "split metacyclic" if I recall correctly.  The term is used in many papers.

Comment: Thanks to both. Do you have an example of a metacyclic group that is not a semidirect product? An example of a non-split metacyclic group?

Comment: The quaternion group of order 8 is a non-split metacyclic group with kernel 4 and index 2.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Thanks to you too.

Comment: Do someone know which conditions must be imposed on $n$ and $m$ in order to have a non abelian split metacyclic group (i.e., $r>1$)?